# How do I programmatically add 'reviews_allowed' to WooCommerce product?

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to add products using data gathered from a Caldera form.  I'm successful in creating the product and adding other attributes, but 'reviews_allowed' is proving to be elusive.

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post(array(
    'post_title' => 'ProductName '.$data['uniquenumber'],
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'draft',
    'post_content' => $data[ 'description' ],
    'post_excerpt' => $data[ 'short_description' ]
));


wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'simple,virtual', 'product_type' );
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, ['services'] ,'product_cat');

wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 1 ,'reviews_allowed' );  // DOESN'T WORK

//update_post_meta( $post_id, 'reviews_allowed', 'yes');  //CREATES SEPARATE ATTRIBUTE,

// All these work though
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'real_name', $data['first_name']." ".$data['last_name'] );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_nyp', 'yes' );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_virtual', 'yes' );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_visibility', 'visible' );
```

I've searched throught the WC code and I'm pretty sure the attribute is 'reviews_allowed' and the type is bool.  I'm new to this, so I hope/expect this is an easy problem.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know `reviews_allowed` in woocommerce is not an object term, attribute, part of the post meta or anything like that.

It's just simply another name for `comment_status` in the post itself.

You can enable reviews when inserting a post using the following

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post(array(
    . . . . 
    'comment_status' => 'open'
));
```

Comment: I personally recommend using the REST API though -- https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs -- through that `reviews_allowed` is a boolean as you stated

Comment: That works, thank you!  I'll look into the REST API as well, but this gets me moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use WordPress post functions when working with WooCommerce products. WooCommerce has its own functions that allow products to properly populate its custom lookup tables and will be forward compatible if (when, realistically) WooCommerce products are moved to a custom data structure in a future version.

You can see some examples [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/developing-using-woocommerce-crud-objects/#section-7), but your code would look like this:

```
$product = new WC_Product_Simple();
$cat_id  = get_term_by( 'slug', 'services', 'product_cat' );

$product->set_category_ids( [ $cat_id ] );
$product->set_name( 'ProductName ' . $data['uniquenumber'] );
$product->set_status( 'draft' );
$product->set_description( $data[ 'description' ] );
$product->set_short_description( $data[ 'short_description' ] );
$product->set_virtual( true );
$product->set_reviews_allowed( true );
$product->set_catalog_visibility( 'visible' );
$product->update_meta_data( 'real_name' );
$product->update_meta_data( '_nyp' );

$product->save();
```

With this method you set the reviews allowed property with `$product->set_reviews_allowed( true );`.